# My tourist visa to Algeria was refused but there is no refusal stamp

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, algerian-citizens, algeria

I applied for a tourist visa to Algeria and it was refused but there was no stamp on the passport showing that it was refused.

I asked for the reason of the refusal and they said that it was due to irregularities on the dossier.

And the receptionist at the embassy said that I cannot apply for another visa to Algeria again.

I am really confused. Because if I cannot apply for visa does that mean I was banned or blacklisted? If Yes, how can I clear my name to at least reapply?

Comment: Looks like you were indeed banned. Try to think about what the irregularities could've been. Then I would contact the second closest Algerian embassy and ask (providing your name) if you're actually banned because your local embassy said you are

Comment: Since at the moment I have recently graduated and I work as a freelancer, so I couldn’t produce a declaration from school or work. Maybe insufficient fund - I have around 800$ on my account. That’s all I can think of.

Comment: Shouldn't cause a ban, just a refusal

Comment: I believe so too because usually if you receive a ban, there should be a stomp or at least a letter trying to explain the reasons

Comment: Usually it would be if you used fraud (or they believe you did). Again, contact your second closest Algerian embassy. Maybe your closest one just doesn't want to deal with you again, in which case they're operating highly unprofessionally.

Comment: There is only one Algerian embassy in the country, the other ones are in the nearest countries.

Comment: Contact those then, and maybe ask the one in your country for a closer explanation. If they won't tell you, you may wish to call the Algerian ministry of foreign affairs (+213 21 50 45 45)

Comment: Did you use any type of agent to help or submit the visa application?

Comment: No, I submitted directly

Comment: VTC: it's difficult to answer, as posed, and in the absence of a refusal document or some sort of official notice. It's both vague (irregularities) and anecdotal (receptionist said...)

Comment: Are you a pastor or teacher? If so, Algeria has been refusing visas without reason. (Google it)

Comment: No, I am not a pastor nor a teacher. I am a recent graduate in IT

Comment: dear can you tell me after how many days thy inform you about visa refusel, coz i applied before 2 months and still no answer, whenever i call consulate thy say we will inform, already more then 2 months now no reply no answers, thats why i want to know after how long thy informed about refusel

Answer (score 2):

It would be impossible to know whether you are banned or were simply refused a visa; the absence of a stamp in your passport is not necessarily an indicator. In this age of electronic information, many countries rely on data for immigration information.  When a visa is refused, usually there is paperwork that accompanies the decision, not an oral communication from an individual at reception (and unlikely to be the one to convey the official stance).

What is left for you to do it either again apply for a visa, correcting any omissions or shortcomings; or contact the Consul General at the embassy in your location. Alternatively, you might contact the Ministry of Foreign Affairs, located 1 Rue Yahia Ibn Batran, El Mouradia, Alger, telephone +213 21 504 545/343, www.mae.dz